# Why use matplotlib instead of some existing software/grapher

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, data-science

Hi, I feel like this question might be completely stupid, but I am still going to ask it, as I have been thinking about it.
What are the advantages, of using a plotter like matplotlib, instead of an existing software, or grapher.
For now, I have guessed that although it takes a lot more time to use such a library, you have more possibilities?

Please, let me know what your opinion is. I am just starting to learn about data science with Python, so I would like to make things clear.

Comment: matplotlib _is_ an "existing software or grapher", you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib gives you a nice level of access:

- you can change all details of the plots, modify ticks, labels, spacing, ...
- it has many sensible defaults, so a oneliner `plot(mydata)` produces fairly nice plots
- it plays well with numpy and other numerical tools, so you can pass your data science objects directly to the plotting tool without going through some intermediate io

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Robin's answer, I think reproducibility is key.

When you make your graphs with matplotlib, since you are coding everything rather than using an interface, all of you work is reproducible, you can just run your script again. Using other software, specifically programs with user interfaces, means that each time you want to remake your graphs, you have to start from scratch, and if someone asks you the specifics of your graph (ie what scale an axis used, what units something is in that might not be labeled) it is difficult for you to go back and figure it out, since there isn't code to examine.